# jQuery dataTables : Add image using mrender

Tags: jquery, html, datatable, datatables

Hi what i want to achieve is being able to add an image column to the datatable from http://www.datatables.net/ . Can anybody help me in rectifying my problem in my code below or do i have to change any part of my code Thanks

```
$('#table_id').DataTable({
    destroy: true,
    data: result,
    columns: [
      { data: 'locationName' }, 
      { data: 'locationDescription' }, 
      { data: 'address' }, 
      { data: 'contactInfo' }, 
      { data: 'openHours' }, 
      { data: 'active' }, 
      {
        "mrender": function(data, type, row) {
            img_str = '<img src="http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/content/ohoopee3.jpg"/>';
            return img_str;
      }
    }],
});
```

Edit

all i want to achieve is able to add a column with an image instead of text

[image of my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBJVW.png)

Comment: `rectifying my problem` what problem?

Comment: the image suppose to come out at the last column but its empty

Comment: can you provide a fiddle which has the problem?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing intrinsically wrong with your code, so I'm going to guess that you only have 6 columns in your HTML, like this:

```
<th>locationName<th>
<th>locationDescription<th>
<th>address<th>
<th>contactInfo<th>
<th>openHours<th>
<th>active<th>
```

So your 7th image column isn't rendered.  If this is the case, just add another `<th><th>` to the HTML.